# PARSE.COM: Fetch data at query

Tags: android, parse-platform

When a query is made in Parse, only the `ObjectId` is downloaded.

Is there any way to download all the columns data in the same call?

If there isn't, which is the quickest way to fetch it al?

This is what I came up with, but since the calls are done 1 after each other, it takes so long to execute.

```
// Create query
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseQuery<Centro> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("...");
query.include(...);
query.whereEqualTo(...);
query.addAscendingOrder(...);

// Execute query
try {
    CLASS = query.find();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    return false;
}

// Force to fetch all data by reading a single column
for (CLASS class : classes){
    try {
        class.fetch();
        class.getSomething();
    } catch (ParseException e) { }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include` function is used to tell Parse to retrieve the contents of other tables too. I thought I had to type the table name in there, however, I had to type the field name instead.

Linking the docs in case anyone is interested: http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/

I realised in the following example, since `Comment` (table name) is uppercase, and line `query.include("post")` specifies `post` in lowercase, it had to be a field name.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");

// Retrieve the most recent ones
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

// Only retrieve the last ten
query.setLimit(10);

// Include the post data with each comment
query.include("post");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {
    // commentList now contains the last ten comments, and the "post"
    // field has been populated. For example:
    for (ParseObject comment : commentList) {
      // This does not require a network access.
      ParseObject post = comment.getParseObject("post");
      Log.d("post", "retrieved a related post");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is does get just get the objectID if you structure your query as in the Docs then you could get something like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FamousPerson");
query.whereEqualTo("name", "Donald Trump");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("person", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
       String myJob = object.getString("Job") //equals "President"

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: True, it's the referenced data what I was missing, due to wrongly typed `include` command in the query.